# Pandas get rows with subtracting rows as a index

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have a function in python that gets the two rows for a yfinance dataframe of tickers. I am doing a calculation, where I make a row that holds the value obtained from subtracting the value, then taking those values and subtracting the second row from the first, then finally taking the rows that are greater than 0.

```
import pandas as pd
import yfinance as yf
import contextlib

def getData(listTickers):
#Suppress all output from yfinance
with contextlib.redirect_stdout(None):
    #Get the prices for the list of symbols
    prices = yf.download(tickers=listTickers, period="5d", interval="1d", auto_adjust=False, prepost=False, threads=True, progress=False, show_error=False)[-2:]
    
    j = prices["Close"] - prices["Open"]
    k = (j.iloc[0] - j.iloc[1])
    s = k[k > 0]

return list(s.index)
```

Is there a way to improve this code or make this more efficient? How can I map a function over the rows that subtracts one row from another? Or is this the most efficient way to do this? Something like:

```
j[j.iloc[0]-j.iloc[1] > 0]
```

Sample input: ["AAPL","MSFT","SPG","GOOGL"]

Sample output: ["AAPL","MSFT"]

Sample prices:
[image]

Comment: Can you provide a sample of the input and expected output?

Comment: Just added it, it's just supposed to filter the list of tickers @Mortz

Comment: Please provide a sample of what `prices` looks like as well.

Comment: Unfortunately I can't format the table to look good in the question but prices is being generated live from downloading the data from yfinance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a combination of `DataFrame` functions to achieve the same result -

```py
import pandas as pd
lol = [[170, 3000, 280, 175, 2800, 240], [170, 3000, 280, 176, 2700, 250]]
prices = pd.DataFrame(lol)
prices.columns = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([['CLOSE', 'OPEN'], ['AAPL', 'AMZN', 'MSFT']])

#Method 1
prices.columns.levels[1][(prices['CLOSE'] - prices['OPEN']).diff().lt(0).loc[1]].tolist()

#Method 2 - using [itertools-compress](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.compress)
# I find this method a little more readable
list(
compress(
prices.columns.levels[1], 
(prices['CLOSE'] - prices['OPEN']).diff().lt(0).loc[1]
)
)
```

With this dummy dataset, the efficiency in terms of `%timeit` are similar for all 3 methods - but these methods are probably closer in terms of your requirement of mapping a function to subtract rows

Comment: Unfortunately, both methods are not working for me. Method 1 is giving me a "KeyError: 1" exception

Comment: Looks like you have dates for the index and not 0 and 1. Either change the `loc` to `iloc` or do a `reset_index` on the prices data